# expand rows with data.table across years

Tags: r, data.table, expand, expansion

I'm looking for a `data.table` solution to expand my dataset to include missing years, assigning zero to values for the missing years.
In the following example:

```
> df <- data.table(firm = rep(c("A","B"),each=4), 
                   year = rep(c(2005,2007,2008,2011),2), var="var")
> df
   firm year var
1:    A 2005 var
2:    A 2007 var
3:    A 2008 var
4:    A 2011 var
5:    B 2005 var
6:    B 2007 var
7:    B 2008 var
8:    B 2011 var
```

A desired output (Solution 1) is:

```
> df
    firm year var
 1:    A 2005 var
 2:    A 2006   0
 3:    A 2007 var
 4:    A 2008 var
 5:    A 2009   0
 6:    A 2010   0
 7:    A 2011 var
 8:    B 2005 var
 9:    B 2006   0
10:    B 2007 var
11:    B 2008 var
12:    B 2009   0
13:    B 2010   0
14:    B 2011 var
```

Further, is there any way I could add prior or next years that are not in my initial dataset, again assigning zero to the other variables. For example, the range of years in my initial dataset was 2005-2011 and say, I want to expand it to 2003-2012, having the following output (Solution 2):

```
> df
    firm year var
 1:    A 2003   0
 2:    A 2004   0
 3:    A 2005 var
 4:    A 2006   0
 5:    A 2007 var
 6:    A 2008 var
 7:    A 2009   0
 8:    A 2010   0
 9:    A 2011 var
10:    B 2012   0
11:    B 2003   0
12:    B 2004   0
13:    B 2005 var
14:    B 2006   0
15:    B 2007 var
16:    B 2008 var
17:    B 2009   0
18:    B 2010   0
19:    A 2011 var
20:    A 2012   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `expand.grid` to generate all possible combinations:

```
library(data.table)

all <- data.table(expand.grid(year=2003:2012,firm =unique(df$firm)))

df[all,.(firm,year,var=fifelse(is.na(var),"0",var)),on=.(year=year,firm=firm)]

    firm year var
 1:    A 2003   0
 2:    A 2004   0
 3:    A 2005 var
 4:    A 2006   0
 5:    A 2007 var
 6:    A 2008 var
 7:    A 2009   0
 8:    A 2010   0
 9:    A 2011 var
10:    A 2012   0
11:    B 2003   0
12:    B 2004   0
13:    B 2005 var
14:    B 2006   0
15:    B 2007 var
16:    B 2008 var
17:    B 2009   0
18:    B 2010   0
19:    B 2011 var
20:    B 2012   0
```

Answer (score 2):

If `tidyverse` is an option, this may be done within `complete` using `nesting` and `fill` as its arguments

```
df %>% complete(year = 2003:2012, nesting(firm), fill = list(var = 0))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
    year firm  var  
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1  2003 A     0    
 2  2003 B     0    
 3  2004 A     0    
 4  2004 B     0    
 5  2005 A     var  
 6  2005 B     var  
 7  2006 A     0    
 8  2006 B     0    
 9  2007 A     var  
10  2007 B     var  
11  2008 A     var  
12  2008 B     var  
13  2009 A     0    
14  2009 B     0    
15  2010 A     0    
16  2010 B     0    
17  2011 A     var  
18  2011 B     var  
19  2012 A     0    
20  2012 B     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(year = 2003:2012, firm = unique(df$firm)) %>%
     left_join(df, by = c('year', 'firm')) %>%
     mutate(var = ifelse(is.na(var), "0", var))
```

---

Or another option is `group_by/complete`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(firm) %>%
  complete(year = 2003:2012, fill = list(var = 0)) %>%
  ungroup
```